# is there any way to integrate Adyen gateway webhook controller in java side to get notified on receive payment event?

Tags: java, api, integration, payment-gateway, adyen

- is there any api available to get details of payment object., need to integrate in java.

-how to handle event from java to get notified on get payment event ,also to get that payment information.

-is authentication for user activity based on only "api-key " or can we generate auth token for authenticate user.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read their [best practices](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/best-practices) page? they explain they use a HMAC signature and optionally a Basic auth can be put in place. We did that on our side and by reading the documentation I found nothing complex, but you have to be more specific on your question to fit the StackOverflow standard.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few questions so I am answering the main handling payment event question.

Adyen uses webhooks to send payment status and other events to your server. You will need to expose an endpoint to handle those events.

Look at Adyen's [documentation on notification webhooks](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks) for more information. You will need to parse the JSON coming from Adyen but they do have some helper methods like for [HMAC validation in Java](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/webhooks/verify-hmac-signatures?tab=codeBlockhmac_validation_1#verify-using-our-libraries).